# What is Asynchronous Web APIs in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, api, rest-api

In Magento Open Source 2.3.0 **[Release Notes](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.3.0OpenSource.html)**

Magento introduced **[Asynchronous web endpoints](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/asynchronous-web-endpoints.html)** in Release Notes.

**Example**

```
PUT /async/V1/products/24-MB01
```

> payload

```
{
  "product": {
    "price": 29
  }
}
```

1. Isn't it same with normal API call ?
2. And is it related to GraphQL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Asynchronous Web APIs**

The only difference with synchronous calls (you can say Normal API call) is

> The route to all asynchronous calls contains the prefix /async, added
>   before /V1 of a standard synchronous endpoint.

**Logical difference**

Asynchronous and bulk web APIs will process API calls without waiting for the whole call queue to be processed. Using this approach greatly reduces the response time from the APIs while processing such API calls as bulk product integration, or customer import. This functionality will be available in both Magento 2.3 Commerce and OpenSource editions.

> For GraphQL

- GraphQL is a query language for APIs. It is one of the modern
  technique to build and query API.
- Magento 2.3 executes GraphQL as an elective API endpoint in addition
  to REST API and SOAP API.

**I hope this will help. I tried to cover all your question query**

Comment: Thanks @Aaditya for appreciation. if my answer is helpful and covered your queries then please kindly accept it so it helps other readers as well. keep coding :) thanks :)

Comment: Yes, I'll. Right now performing some cases for Asynchronous APIs from devdocs.